# Use shift and tab key together in Sikuli

Tags: automation, key, sikuli

Using this script in the Sikuli IDE to run through a form. How do I use the shift and tab keys together to go back to previous fields?

```
type("w" + Key.TAB
    + "6378678&*(^%" + Key.TAB
    + "w" + Key.TAB
    + "6378678&*(^%" + Key.TAB
    + "w" + Key.TAB
    + "6378678&*(^%" + Key.TAB
    + "w" + Key.TAB
    + "6378678&*(^%" + Key.TAB
    + "w" + Key.TAB
    + "6378678&*(^%" + Key.TAB)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what all these symbols you have included, but try:

```
type(Key.TAB, KeyModifier.SHIFT)
```

Comment: Those were just test parameters for invalid entries. Your solution works great. Thanks! I was trying to do it backwards using the Key.SHIFT and KeyModifier.TAB....

Comment: @Eugene There is an extra quotation mark in your example that is not needed. This: type(Key.TAB, KeyModifier.SHIFT) would do the trick.

Comment: @Tenzin It's removed now :) Thanks